# oncanplaythrough not firing

Tags: javascript, audio, garbage-collection

I am preloading some sounds to use them later in my program. The code goes like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
        console.log("loaded");
    });
    audio.src = urlList[i];
}
```

I don't need to store the Audio objects anywhere, since I create new ones later on. As I learnt, if I load it once, it won't load it again, if it's the same file, so my approach is okay in this sense.

What is not okay is that sometimes the event won't fire at all! I added the console.log to check it out.

Now, my guess is that it's the garbage collector that sees some non-referenced object and disposes it. Are my concerns right? How can I prevent this? Even if I store them into some variable, it could be disposed as soon as the script finishes. I need to wait until the sound loads and the event fires.

Comment: _"What is not okay is that sometimes the event won't fire at all!"_ Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr https://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why do you not store the requested resources?